# JQuery - get very next element in my html structure

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following Html structure (it is a snippet from a larger piece of code).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="margin-bottom:1em;clear:both">
                <input value="0" type="text" id="someTextField" disabled>
                <button type="button" class="someClass" disabled></button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to add an event handler to the input text-element, that checks whether it is disabled or not. If it is disabled, the button shall not be displayed.

I tried several JQuery-solutions (like `.next()` or `.closest()`) from other questions, but wasn't able to select the button element if my current object is the input element.

If I do: `$JQ('#someTextField').closest()` I get an empty array as a result.

If I do: `$JQ('someTextField').parent().next('someClass')` I get an empty array as well.

I am rather new to JQuery, so I might miss something quite obvious.

Comment: did you try `$('#someTextField').next('.someClass')`?

Comment: I tried. I get an empty array as well.

Comment: use .next() WITHOUT .parent()

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't in the right frame. I got an empty array when I did the request frome outside the iframe in which the elements are contained. Being inside the simple snippet `$JQ('#someTextField').next('button')` worked fine for me! I wasn't aware that iframes cause such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.next()` enough. You are trying to get the next sibling button

```
$JQ('#someTextField').next('.someClass')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing class selector `.` while targeting next element:

```
$(function(){ //or $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#someTextField').next('.someClass')
});
```

Comment: @Rattlesnake: have you wrapped the code in document ready event

Comment: If I execute it in the google dev tool without the "document ready event" I get an empty array. Using it I get the whole document as a result.

Comment: @Rattlesnake: can you create problem fiddle and share the link?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  alert($("#someTextField").parent().find(".someClass").attr("type"));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="margin-bottom:1em;clear:both">
        <input value="0" type="text" id="someTextField" disabled>
        <button type="button" class="someClass" disabled></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can access it as shown in the above example

Comment: This doesn't necessarily find the .someClass right next to .someTextField, it'll not work as expected if there are several .someClass elements

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="margin-bottom:1em;clear:both">
                <input value="0" type="text" id="someTextField" disabled>
                <button type="button" class="someClass" disabled></button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {

    enter code here

  if($('someTextField').is(':disabled')){
      $(".someClass").hide();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if it doesn't there's something fishy going on.
It selects the disabled input field and then hides the next element if it has .someClass. If there is no disabled input field, nothing is selected. If the next element doesn't have the class .someClass, nothing is hidden.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#someTextField:disabled').next('.someClass').hide();  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="margin-bottom:1em;clear:both">
        <input value="0" type="text" id="someTextField" disabled="disabled">
        <button type="button" class="someClass" disabled="disabled">Test</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('someTextField').is(':disabled')){
   $('#someTextField').next('.someClass').hide();
}
```